# Definite integral of a rational fraction

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, factoring

Can I find the value of $$\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}dx$$ by just  factoring the fraction?

I tried to wrote:
$$\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}=\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x+1-4)^2}=\frac{x-1}{[(x-1)^2-2^2]^2}=\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2\cdot(x-3)^2}$$ but didn't work out. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the substitution $u = x^2-2x-3$ (what is $du$?)

Comment: The integral is divergent !!!.
$$
{x - 1 \over \left(x^{2} - 2x - 3\right)^{2}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mathrm{as}\ x\ \to\ 3^{\large +}}{\sim}\,\,\,
{1 \over 8}\,{1 \over \left(x - 3\right)^{2}}
$$

Comment: On the theme "How To Make Complex Things Simple", have you seen the method of @rogerl ? There is definitely no profit to factorize the denominator for the purpose in question.

Answer (score 2):

write $$\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}$$ as $$-1/8\, \left( x+1 \right) ^{-2}+1/8\, \left( x-3 \right) ^{-2}$$
use that $$\frac{(x-1)}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}=\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2(x-3)^2}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x-3}+\frac{D}{(x-3)^2}$$
it is 
$$\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}=\frac{A(x+1)(x-3)^2+B(x-3)^2+C(x-3)(x+1)^2+D(x+1)^2}{(x+1)^2(x-3)^2}$$

Comment: how from $\frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}$ I get that?

Comment: @LeosKotrop You can start from this: $\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x-3}+\frac{D}{(x-3)^2}$, then bring fractions to a common denominator. Then you compare the nominator you receive with $x-1$. This way you can find $A, B, C$ and $D$ that you are looking for.

Comment: @LeosKotrop in this case though, $A$ and $C$ can be omitted.  $ \frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{D}{(x-3)^2} = \frac{B(x-3)^2+D(x+1)^2}{(x-3)^2(x+1)^2} = \frac{x^2(B+D)+x(-6B+2D)+9B+D}{(x-3)^2(x+1)^2} = \frac{x-1}{(x-3)^2(x+1)^2}$. So, you have: $B+D=0, \quad$  $-6B+2D=1  \, \, \; $ and $  \; \, \, 9B+D=-1$, which is fulfilled by $B=-\frac{1}{8}$ and $ D=\frac{1}{8}$, just like Dr. Sonnhard Graubner gave us :-)

Answer (score 1):

With $u=x^2-2x-3$ we have $du = 2(x-1)\,dx$, so that
$$\int \frac{x-1}{(x^2-2x-3)^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2}\,du
     = -\frac{1}{2u} + c= -\frac{1}{2(x^2-2x-3)}+c.$$

Comment: [+1] How easy !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fraction decomposition, that is, find $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}$ such that$$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2(x-3)^2}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{(x+1)^2}+\frac C{x-3}+\frac D{(x-3)^2}.$$